Pi-Connect does it allow for Passthrough audio?
Audio Question on Pi5: When using with Pi-Connect does it allow for Passthrough audio? I'm attempting from my PC to connect to the Pi5 and play a you tube video. But I'm unable to hear any Audio. Based on what I have read it says it can be done, The pi5 has HDMI selected as audio output. I'm using a LCD TV as my monitor with 3 HDMI's have tried all of the ports. When the PI5 is connect directly to the TV via HDMI it plays just fine. But once I try to connect using Pi-Connect I get no audio. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated. Thank in advance.

so you want the audio to play from the monitor connected to the pi? or on whatever you connect with?

Anything would be preferable of course.   Playing video from youtube bout watching thru the HDMI to a TV.  Works just fine.  But when I connect via pi-connect and view from my PC I can see the video but hear no sound.  So it seems Pi-connect does not pass Audio.  But when I look that question up it claims it does.
